# Quadratic residues and index w.r.t. primitive root of a odd prime p

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a problem in solving my number theory homework. My question is as follows:

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Prove that $a$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ if and only if the $I_{g}(x)$ (index with respect to any primitive root of $p$) is even.

Please edit my writing. Thanks. Does anyone know where to start? Thank you very much for everything!

Comment: I hope my editing of the format was appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Let $\rm\:c\:$ be a primitive root. If $\rm\ a \equiv b^2\: $ and $\rm\ b \equiv c^k\ $ then $\rm\ a \equiv (\cdots)^2\ $ so $\rm\:a\:$ has even index. Conversely suppose $\rm\:a\:$ has even index  $\rm\ I_c(a) = 2\ k\:.\:$ Then $\rm\ a \equiv (\cdots)^2\ $ so $\rm\:a\:$ is a quadratic residue.

Essentially the proof boils down to  $\rm\ (c^k)^2 \equiv c^{2 k}\,$ and $\rm\,2k\,$ stays even when reduced mod $\,\rm 2m = p\!-\!1.\,$ It easily generalizes from $\rm\ 2\to n\,$ when $\,\rm n\mid p-1.$

Comment: @Bill: Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Thank you! How to show that if p is odd prime and g is a primitive root mod p, then index of g (mod p-1) = (p-1)/2 (mod p-1)

Comment: @Kira: Do you mean the index of $-1\:,\:$ i.e. $\rm\ I_g(-1)\ $?

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: This is the question: If p is an odd prime and g is a primitive root mod p, then I_g (p-1) = (p-1)/2 (mod p-1). Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Kira: That's better. Hint: $\rm\ x = g^{(p-1)/2}\ \Rightarrow\ x^2\equiv 1\:.\ $ But $\rm\ x\not\equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\ x \equiv\ \cdots$

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Thanks for clarification!

Comment: @BillDubuque:  I put essentially your argument in a comment to a recent [duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271719/show-that-a-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-iff-ind-r-mathbba-is-even), but I was concerned it is incomplete:  to argue that $a$ has even index, do we have to argue that not only is $c^{2k}=a,$ as we have done, but also that there is no positive odd number $m$ less than $2k$ for which $c^m=a$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner If $\,2k > p\!-\!1\,$ then $\,2k\bmod (p-1) = 2k-(p\!-\!1)$ remains even, by $\,p-1\,$ is even. More generally $\,j\,$ and $\,j\bmod 2m\,$ have equal parity by $\ (j\bmod 2m)\bmod 2\, =\, j\bmod 2\ \ $

Comment: Thanks @BillDubuque, and I guess if there were an odd number $m$ less than $2k-(p-1)$ for which $c^m=a$ then $c$ would not be a primitive root

Comment: J.W.Tanner Yes, the index is unique since the exponential map $\, k\to c^k\,$ is an isomorphism of the the additive group of $\,\Bbb Z_{p-1}$ with the multiplicative group of $\,\Bbb Z_p,\,$  so, in particular, it is a bjection on the underlying sets. $\ \ $