# Show that a is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ iff $ind_{r} (\mathbb{a})$ is even.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be an odd prime with primitive root $r$. Let $\mathbb{a}$ be an integer with $gcd(\mathbb{a},p) =1$ and $ind_{r} (\mathbb{a})$ denote the index of $\mathbb{a}$ relative to $r$.
 Show that $\mathbb{a}$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ iff $ind_{r} (\mathbb{a})$ is even.

Could anyone give me a hint for solving this, please?

For the *index of an integer w.r.t quadratic residue*, Please follow the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue).

Comment: if $r^{2k}\equiv a$ then $(r^k)^2\equiv a$ so...; on the other hand, if $a\equiv x^2$ then $x\equiv r^k$ so...

Comment: What do you mean by ind_{r} (a)?

Comment: Use this answer to edit the above question.https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference @hopefully I hope that OP edits it to explain. Then maybe I could the details for the question.

Comment: @Kumar I mean index of a  relative to the primitive root r

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  you mean in the other direction we can take $x = r^k$ and so the index of a will be the even number 2k ........ correct?